# Each table with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have this my ajax, which makes the table

```
$("#addOpcaoTreino").on('click', function(){
        var users_id = $("#users_id option:selected").val();
        if(users_id){
            $.ajax({
                url: "/admin/anamnese/getLesoesList",
                type:"GET",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: 'users_id=' + users_id,
                success:function(response){
                    var trHTML = '';

                    $.each(response, function(i, item){
                        trHTML += '<tr>';
                        trHTML += '<th>' + 'Lesão: ' + item.lesoes["nome"] + '</th>';
                        trHTML += '</tr>';
                        trHTML += '<tr>';
                        trHTML += '<td>' + 'Tipo: ' + item.tipos["nome"] + '</td>';
                        trHTML += '</tr>';
                        trHTML += '<tr>'
                        trHTML += '<td>' + 'Local: ' + item.locais["nome"] + '</td>';
                        trHTML += '</tr>';
                    });

                    $("#contModal").append(trHTML);
                    //Abre o modal pelo id
                    $('#modalLesoes').modal('show');
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

It looks like this in the preview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MO5F0.png)

I would like it to be like this, where Name, Age, and Profession was the name of the injury and just below the type and location. How do I do that?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFNWk.png)

Comment: Whats the format of ajax response?

Comment: It's coming like json, but actually I want to know how it does there in HTML, which is coming out in list.

Comment: show please `console.log(response)`, it's hard to understand what you're using and what you wanna add